# JQuery library code not executing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using [Google's JQuery MsgBox library](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-msgbox/) to display messages on screen. Below is my code to execute JQuery from code-behind:

```
  public static void GetScript(System.Web.HttpResponse r, string customErrorMessage)
    {
        r.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function($){new $.msgbox('Hello world').show()};</script>");
    }
```

Where I am going wrong? The parameters are passed correctly, but the Script code is not executing. If I simply put: Alert('....'), it works, but JQuery is not working.

My ASP.NET 2.0 application uses Master Page and the above code resides in a Content Form. I checked the LINK tags in the Master Page. The paths are correct and all needed files are referenced correctly.

**Edited**

Updated code as below:

```
public static void GetScript(System.Web.HttpResponse r, string customErrorMessage)
{
    string[] dependencyFiles = { "/Resources/JQueryScripts/Core/jquery.min.js",
                                 "/Resources/JQueryScripts/MsgBox/jquery.msgbox.js",
                                 "/Resources/JQueryScripts/MsgBox/jquery.dragndrop.min.js",
                                 "/Resources/JQueryScripts/MsgBox/jquery.msgbox.css" };

    r.AddFileDependencies(dependencyFiles);
    r.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>function($){new $.msgbox('Hello world').show()}</script>");
}
```

**Edited**
It is showing error: `Sys is undefined`, when debug is enabled in IE. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: "all needed files are referenced correctly." Have you applied the jQuery library somewhere in the HttpResponse r?

Comment: @Topi: I am not getting what you mean. I added the references to all JQuery scripts in the HEAD section of the Master Page.

Comment: See updated code in original post.

Answer (score 0):

try

`<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>$(function(){new $.msgbox('Hello world').show()});</script>`

Comment: No errors. The rest of the application is running well. I pasted the call-code on Page Load. It doesn't displays a message but loads the Page correctly.

Comment: I enabled IE built-in debugger, which is giving error: "Object Expected" in the above Javascript code.

Comment: Could you post the generated html/javascript for us? Maybe that can help us solve this problem.

Comment: this seems more like another issue. Maybe this post can help out: http://www.jwc3.net/2008/07/sys-is-undefined-aspnet-ajax.html especially the line `if (typeof(Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();` might help?

Comment: But it is also giving error in your Javascript code: Object Expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the drag drop file above your msgbox javascript file